# Cut command in AIX

Tags: aix, cut, linux-disk-free

We would like to automate the disk cleanup process by using a shell script on an AIX 7. We need to write a shell script to clean disk according to disk percentage

Sample output of df -Pg

```
user:host:/:>df -Pg

Filesystem    GB blocks      Used Available Capacity Mounted on

/dev/hd4           5.00      0.05      4.95       2% /

/dev/hd2           6.00      3.63      2.37      61% /usr

/dev/work1lv   1074.50    377.46    697.04      36% /work1

... some lines are ommitted and it continues
```

We want to check only capacity percentage by using cut command
We couldnt list only 5th column that is given as parameter to cut command -f. If we succeeded displaying properly, we will continue for cleaning part using shell script.

`df -Pg | cut -f5 -d'      '`

The output of the command above was not what we expect.

Comment: I would start with sg like this: `COLUMNS=1024 df  | sed -n 's/^\([^ ]*\) .*\( [^ ]*\)%.*$/\1 \2/p'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cut` command considers each and every delimiter to begin a new field; if you told it to delimit the output based on spaces and tabs, every space creates a new field. That's why you got unexpected output.

Printing field 5 could be done more directly with `awk`, which combines any number of sequential spaces into one delimiter: `df -Pg | awk '{print $5}'`. You still have two problems to solve, though: skipping the header and considering filesystems that have a space in their mount-point. You can skip the header fairly easily, since it's the first line of output: `df -Pg | awk 'NR > 1 {print $5}'`, but dealing with the remaining fields takes more work.

I would propose that you use different options for [the `df` command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/d_commands/df.html) to request colon-separated output with specific fields: `df -c -F %z %m`. The `-F` option automatically includes the filesystem device and block fields, so you'd want to skip those. We still want to skip the header, so we end up with:

```
df -c -F %z %m | sed 1d | cut -d: -f3,4
```

... to delete the first line, then output only the third and fourth colon-delimited fields. That should give your monitoring program the relevant information. Depending on what actions you're taking, you may want to include field 1 (the device) if you need to check the free volume group space. Be aware that the `df` output adds a space to the beginning of the mount-point field (which may be a side effect of requesting colon-separated output and its parsing of the -F argument). Be aware also that you may see network-mounted filesystems; if you only want to see local filesystems, add the `-T local` option:

```
df -T local -c -F %z %m | sed 1d | cut -d: -f3,4
```